# Row-wise conditional formatting in Shiny Reactable table

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-formatting, reactable

I have the following dataframe that I am importing into a Shiny app:

```
final_odds <- structure(list(player_prop = c("Aaron Jones: Rush + Rec Yards", 
                                             "Aaron Jones: Rush + Rec Yards", "Aaron Rodgers: Interceptions", 
                                             "Aaron Rodgers: Interceptions", "Aaron Rodgers: Pass TDs", "Aaron Rodgers: Pass TDs", 
                                             "Aaron Rodgers: Pass Yards", "Aaron Rodgers: Pass Yards", "Adam Thielen: Rec Yards", 
                                             "Adam Thielen: Rec Yards"), Side = c("Over", "Under", "Over", 
                                                                                  "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under"), 
                             DraftKings = c("1300.5 (-115)", "1300.5 (-115)", "7.5 (115)", 
                                            "7.5 (-140)", "31.5 (-120)", "31.5 (100)", "4050.5 (-110)", 
                                            "4050.5 (-110)", "750.5 (-110)", "750.5 (-120)"), BetMGM = c("-", 
                                                                                                         "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "699.5 (-125)", "699.5 (-105)"
                                            ), FanDuel = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "30.5 (-112)", "30.5 (-112)", 
                                                           "3950.5 (-112)", "3950.5 (-112)", "750.5 (-112)", "750.5 (-112)"
                                            ), Caesars = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "30.5 (-115)", "30.5 (-115)", 
                                                           "4000.5 (-115)", "4000.5 (-115)", "775.5 (-115)", "775.5 (-115)"
                                            )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                            ))
```

What I want to do is make it so that the lowest value (of the numbers not in parentheses) in columns 3-6 is highlighted in green for each row of data. The complications here are two-fold: 1) there isn't always a value in each of the columns, and 2) I just need to evaluate the numbers outside of the parentheses.

Here is a basic outline of the Shiny app as it stands:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)


final_odds <- structure(list(player_prop = c("Aaron Jones: Rush + Rec Yards", 
                                             "Aaron Jones: Rush + Rec Yards", "Aaron Rodgers: Interceptions", 
                                             "Aaron Rodgers: Interceptions", "Aaron Rodgers: Pass TDs", "Aaron Rodgers: Pass TDs", 
                                             "Aaron Rodgers: Pass Yards", "Aaron Rodgers: Pass Yards", "Adam Thielen: Rec Yards", 
                                             "Adam Thielen: Rec Yards"), Side = c("Over", "Under", "Over", 
                                                                                  "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under", "Over", "Under"), 
                             DraftKings = c("1300.5 (-115)", "1300.5 (-115)", "7.5 (115)", 
                                            "7.5 (-140)", "31.5 (-120)", "31.5 (100)", "4050.5 (-110)", 
                                            "4050.5 (-110)", "750.5 (-110)", "750.5 (-120)"), BetMGM = c("-", 
                                                                                                         "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "-", "699.5 (-125)", "699.5 (-105)"
                                            ), FanDuel = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "30.5 (-112)", "30.5 (-112)", 
                                                           "3950.5 (-112)", "3950.5 (-112)", "750.5 (-112)", "750.5 (-112)"
                                            ), Caesars = c("-", "-", "-", "-", "30.5 (-115)", "30.5 (-115)", 
                                                           "4000.5 (-115)", "4000.5 (-115)", "775.5 (-115)", "775.5 (-115)"
                                            )), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
                                            ))



ui <- fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("odds_table")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

    output$odds_table <- renderReactable({
    reactable(final_odds)
  })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 3):

We may get the index of the `min` values from columns 3 to 6 by looping `across` those columns, get the number outside the `()` with `parse_number`, find the `min` and get the index with `which`

```
library(dplyr)
library(reactable)
final_odds1 <-  final_odds %>%
          summarise(across(3:6, ~ {
              x1 <- readr::parse_number(.x)
              which(x1 %in% min(x1, na.rm = TRUE))
          }))
```

Now, we create the `reactable` object by specifying the `columns` and loop over the row `index` in `style` to highlight the rows where they are `min`imum by comparing with the index stored data from 'final_odds1'

```
reactable(final_odds, columns = list(
  DraftKings = colDef(
    style = function(value, index) {
      if(index %in% final_odds1$DraftKings) {
        color <- "green"
      } else {
        color <- "black"
      }
      list(color = color)
        
      
      
    }
  ),
  BetMGM = colDef(
    style = function(value, index) {
      if(index %in% final_odds1$BetMGM) {
        color <- "green"
      } else {
        color <- "black"
      }
      list(color = color)
      
      
      
    }
  ),
  FanDuel = colDef(
    style = function(value, index) {
      if(index %in% final_odds1$FanDuel) {
        color <- "green"
      } else {
        color <- "black"
      }
      list(color = color)
      
      
      
    }
  ), 
  
  
  Caesars = colDef(
    style = function(value, index) {
      if(index %in% final_odds1$Caesars) {
        color <- "green"
      } else {
        color <- "black"
      }
      list(color = color)
      
      
      
    }
  )
  
  
))
```

-output

[image]

---

If there are many columns, create a function wrapper and then loop over the names with `map` or `imap`

```
library(purrr)
final_odds1 <-  final_odds %>%
          summarise(across(3:6, ~ {
              x1 <- readr::parse_number(.x)
              which(x1 %in% min(x1, na.rm = TRUE))
          }))


style_fun <- function(colnm) {
        colDef(
          style =  function(value, index) {
            if(index %in% final_odds1[[colnm]]) {
              color <- "green"
            } else {
              color <- "black"
            }
            list(color = color)
            
            
            
          }
        )
  
  
  
}
reactable(final_odds, 
 columns = setNames(map(names(final_odds)[3:6], 
      ~ style_fun(.x)), names(final_odds[3:6])))
```

---

If it is grouped by 'player_prop'

```
library(stringr)
final_odds1 <-  final_odds %>%
          mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
          group_by(player_prop) %>%
          mutate(across(DraftKings:Caesars, ~ {
              x1 <- as.numeric(na_if(str_remove(.x, "\\s*\\(.*"), "-"))
              
              list(if(all(is.na(x1))) NA_integer_ else 
      rn[x1 %in% min(x1, na.rm = TRUE)])
              
          })) %>%
        ungroup


style_fun <- function(colnm) {
        colDef(
          style =  function(value, index) {
            if(index %in% final_odds1[[colnm]][[index]]) {
              color <- "green"
            } else {
              color <- "black"
            }
            list(color = color)
            
            
            
          }
        )
  
  
  
}
reactable(final_odds, columns = setNames(map(names(final_odds)[3:6],
      ~ style_fun(.x)), names(final_odds[3:6])))
```

Comment: I realized I didn't clarify in my original post, but I wanted to find the minimum in each column by group of the `player_prop` column - how would you change the code to reflect that?

Comment: @SamHoppen you may need  the `final_odds1` as `group_by(player_prop)` before the `summarise` step or create new columns with `mutate` after grouping in the same data (which would be better).  I will update

Comment: @SamHoppen with gruoped by 'player_prop, from your example, it is all distinct values.  Thus all the elements will green?

Comment: @SamHoppen I updated the code, but your example may not be reflecting the correct change

Comment: yeah it doesn't seem to be working for me. I get values like "1:2" as cell values when I use the updated code.

Comment: @SamHoppen It works fine for me though.  can you check the `final_odds1` data.  Those are list columns.  which I subset in the reactable code